# ngTable with ng-if is not working

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ng-table with angularJs as shown below.My problem is when I use ngTable it's rendered same column twice (MyColumn).In other words it doesn't consider the ng-if.How can I get rid of that issue ?

**Note :** But for the normal table it's working fine.Why is that not working with the ngTable ?

**[ngTable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/)**

```
<table ng-table="TableParams" class="table" template-pagination="custom/pager">

    <tr ng-repeat="item in My.Items">
      <td ng-if="(item.Value | uppercase) == 'NO'" data-title="'MyColumn'" sortable="'Value'">{{item.Value}}</td>
       <td ng-if="(item.Value | uppercase) == 'YES'" data-title="'MyColumn'" sortable="'Value'">{{item.Value}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: never mind, sorry, for what you are doing you actually want to use ng-if

Comment: @Josep Yes.But it's not working when I use the ngTable. But for normal table it's working fine.Why is that ?

Comment: it works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/m8XNtkiywlicJmbJifun?p=preview , so I don't know what to say.

Comment: Have you tried using ng-switch? ng-if is supposed to be evaluated only once.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos How can I use ng-switch with above scenario.B'cos "tr" doesn't allow me to put "div" inside it.Do you have any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it as shown below.It works fine. Hurray :D

```
  <tr ng-repeat="item in My.Items">

   <td data-title="'MyColumn'" sortable="'Value'">

      <span ng-if="(item.Value | uppercase) == 'NO'">{{item.Value}}</span>
      <span ng-if="(item.Value | uppercase) == 'YES'">{{item.Value}}</span>

   </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Yes Bro.I'll do that.But I have to wait 2 days for it.Thanks. :) @NitsanBaleli